# Unable to access image form android emulator

Tags: android

[image]

I am building a simple app which has a image button, when clicked should launch a gallery intent and allows user to select an image form gallery.
Here is the code to launch the gallery intent:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("Image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

The problem is that the option to select image gets blurred out and I'm not able to select it.

Comment: have you tried run it using real device ?

Comment: Yes, it works fine on my phone.

Comment: Your problem are image looked blurry ?

Comment: Nope, the option to select image gets blurred out and I'm not able to select it.

Comment: can you post the layout ? Look like the listview is not clickable.

Comment: The list view is not form my application code, it is the phones list view on launching the gallery intent.

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_IMAGE);  use this

Comment: @PravinSuthar Agree with you to use that method.

Comment: @PravinSuthar, your code had some errors, I modified it to  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_REQUEST); and it works